# How to remove "Read on" content in the_excerpt?

Tags: excerpt

I know the_content has the handy dandy $strip_teaser argument that lets you set whether there is "continue reading" text. No such luck for the_excerpt...

I would like to just get rid of it. I had previously tried to just shorten it to Read on but that didn't seem to work either.

```
 function beernews_auto_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return ' &hellip;' . __( 'Read on <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyeleven' ) . '</a>';

}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'beernews_auto_excerpt_more' );
```

Theme is Twenty Eleven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the Twenty Eleven theme I think you need to remove that theme's filter before you can define your own:

remove_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'twentyeleven_auto_excerpt_more' );

*edit* building from t-p

try this:

```
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_child_theme_setup' );
    function my_child_theme_setup() {
       remove_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'twentyten_auto_excerpt_more' );
    }
```

In case you are using twentyeleven, use "twentyeleven_auto_excerpt_more" instead of 'twentyten_auto_excerpt_more'

Comment: Just that line? I placed it above the other code and it didn't work.

Comment: see my edit above

Comment: Thank you!! Guess I should have read twentyeleven's functions.php from the top. :)

Answer (score 1):

I use this in my twenty ten child theme,s functions.php:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_child_theme_setup' );
function my_child_theme_setup() {
remove_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'twentyten_excerpt_length' );
}
```

Comment: Speaking of excerpt_length, I wonder if there is a new function to use characters instead of words a la Twitter.