# Remove "Continue Reading" Link From the Teaser Excerpt Only

Tags: excerpt

I want to remove the "Continue Reading" link from the teaser excerpt only and not from the automatic excerpt, which filter is easily available.

This is the original code; it's from the Showcase Template Page Template:

```
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php
    if ( '' != get_the_content() )
        get_template_part( 'content', 'intro' );
?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Here is the Intro:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . __( 'Pages:', 'mytheme' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
    <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'mytheme' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

-->

Comment: We need to see all of your code, could you post the contents of content-intro.php? Might want to look up what get_template_part does =p

Answer (score 2):

Change standard text for all excerpts:

```
function custom_excerpt_more($more) {
   global $post;
   $more_text = '...';
   return '… <a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . $more_text . '</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'custom_excerpt_more');
```

Create your own excerpt function:

```
// Rafael Marques Excerpt Function ;)
function rm_excerpt($limit = null, $separator = null) {

    // Set standard words limit
    if (is_null($limit)){
        $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), '15');
    } else {
        $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
    }

    // Set standard separator
    if (is_null($separator)){
        $separator = '...';
    }

    // Excerpt Generator
    if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
        array_pop($excerpt);
        $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).$separator;
    } else {
        $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
    }   
    $excerpt = preg_replace('`\[[^\]]*\]`','',$excerpt);
    echo $excerpt;
}
```

Use `<?php rm_excerpt(); ?>` when you want display custom excerpt. First value set words limit and second value set separator. Example: `<?php rm_excerpt(10,' (...)'); ?>`. To create separate link "read more", insert `<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">Read More?</a>`

Comment: Okay, so there is no specific filter that modifies the teaser only?

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'wpsites_read_more_link' );
function wpsites_read_more_link() {
return '<a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '"></a>';
}
```

Add this to your functions file and it will remove the more link.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to remove the "Continue Reading" teaser from the_content(). If so, this example from the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More) would be what you need:

> **Read More Techniques**
>
> The parameters within the template tag the_content() are as follows:
>
> `<?php the_content( $more_link_text , $strip_teaser ); ?>`
>
> The $more_link_text sets the link text like "Read More". The second
>   one, $strip_teaser, sets whether or not the "more" link should be
>   hidden (TRUE) or displayed (FALSE). The default is FALSE, which shows
>   the link text.
>
> To remove the teaser:
>
> Change the_content(); in your index.php to (i.e., the second parameter controls this):
>
> ```
> `the_content('',TRUE,'');`
> ```
>
> Include `<!--noteaser-->` in the post text, immediately after the `<!--more-->`.

**UPDATE**
Based on your code, it looks like you have added the code in the wrong place. Without seeing your files, you probably need to go to content.php and look for the_content() and make the change there. I checked it on one of my themes that uses templates and it works fine. You should also read up more on templates, so you understand how they function. In short:

1 - Remove this text from your code:  if ( '' != get_the_content('',TRUE,'') )
2 - Go to content.php in your theme and find the_content() and change it to `the_content('',TRUE,'')`
3 - Add `<!--noteaser-->` as indicated above

This is if you are using `<!--more-->` to manually setup the excerpts.

Comment: Hi chowwy -- I saw that and assumed that it removes the teaser altogether instead of just removing the Continue Reading link. Is this not correct?

Comment: It looks like $strip_teaser indicates whether the "more" link should be hidden/shown. Doesn't indicate that the excerpt itself is removed.

Comment: chowwy -- doesn't work. Notice that it says to put the <!--noteaser--> tag after the more tag, which does not apply to teaser excerpts because they don't have more tags. Does this make sense? I tried inserted the <!--noteaser--> in the editor anyway and got nothing.

Comment: Marcus, do you have some code we can see? Is this in the loop as the_content() or are you using the_excerpt() somewhere else?

Comment: I just put it in the question

Comment: Marcus, I've updated my answer.

Comment: To be clear, how can you insert <!--noteaser--> in the manual excerpt field after the <!--more--> tag when the manual excerpt field does not use the <!--more--> tag by default? I don't think we're talking about the same thing.

Comment: When I say manual excerpt, it means you are deciding where to cut the text within the post editor, not using the separate excerpt field. If you are using the excerpt field, this question/answer might be helpful - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26837/how-to-remove-read-on-content-in-the-excerpt

Comment: This is why I used the word "teaser," because at times WP conflates the "manual excerpt" with the "teaser excerpt," such as you see [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt) where it distinguishes between the teaser and the manual excerpt: "The manual WordPress excerpt is often confused with the automatic excerpt or with the teaser (the part of a post that appears on the front page when you use the More tag). While both are related to the manual excerpt, they are different from it."

Comment: Marcus, the article you linked to indicates that the teaser is the part of a post that appears on the front page when you use the More tag. That's why I provided you with an answer that deals with the teaser. Best of luck to you.

Comment: I am so sorry. Been up since 3:30 on this job and completely misread the codex when I opened the ticket. Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: No problem. Hope you figure everything out.

Answer (score 0):

```
//.... get_the_content() .....//
```

Just edit this part like this: `get_the_content("")`

With this `""` you will make content empty. So just you would have your content text without read more link :-)

Answer (score -2):

I had to go into the **wp-includes** folder, inside the **formatting.php** file and edit line 3284 and change the default number of words to include in the excerpt to a huge number like so:

```
    $excerpt_length = apply_filters( 'excerpt_length', 550000000000000 );
```

The default is only 55

Comment: You should avoid editing core files like `formatting.php` if at all possible, because they will continue to change when you upgrade. Instead use the `excerpt_length` filter to change the value.